# Specifying screen location of an image overlay

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android, I know how to overlay two images and to animate them. The question is how to overlay the second image at a specific location over the first image.

As an example, the first image is the image of an appliance with a power switch, the second image is the power LED that will glow when animated.

I would like to know how I can specify the location of the power LED in the overlay so that it covers the power switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to put both images inside a `FrameLayout`, with the width/height on both set to `wrap_content`.  The last one you add to the `FrameLayout` will be on top.  Then you can position the two images independently in one of several ways:

1) You could set the `layout_gravity` of both items to `top|left`, then set `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginLeft` to position the two images relative to the upper left corner of the `FrameLayout`.

2) If you want to, say center image B on top of image A, you could set image A to `layout_gravity top|left`, `layout_marginLeft` 0, `layout_marginTop` 0, then set `layout_gravity` on image B to `center`.  This approach is a bit more robust with respect to running on various devices.  You can even use the margins to offset image B with respect to its centered position.

You should get the idea at this point.  You can combine `layout_gravity` along with margins to position the images as you need.

Some caveats:

1) This is not a very efficient way to go about things.  If it's just two images in a larger layout, no big deal.  But rendering performance will suffer if you do this technique many times in a layout.  If that's the case, you should consider creating a custom view instead.

2) You need to explicitly set the `layout_gravity` on an item contained within a `FrameLayout`.  Otherwise `FrameLayout` will ignore the `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginLeft` attributes on your child views.

Finally, you can do this same trick with `RelativeLayout`, using its attributes to position the images in relation to one another.  Like `FrameLayout`, the last view added to the layout shows up on top of the others.